# Add New Category in PrestaShop via Web Services use c#

Tags: c#, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to add new category in prestashop 1.5 via web services using `c#`. I made this successfuly with `PHP` but I couldn't make with `C#`

My Code in `PHP` is below and works fine.

```
function PS_new_category($n_is_root_category, $n_id_parent, $n_id_parent, $n_active, $n_l_id,$n_l_id_sec, $n_name, $n_desc, $n_link_rewrite, $n_meta_title, $n_meta_description, $n_meta_keywords) {

global $webService;

$xml = $webService -> get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/categories?schema=blank'));
$resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
unset($resources -> id);
unset($resources -> position);
unset($resources -> id_shop_default);
unset($resources -> date_add);
unset($resources -> date_upd);
$resources -> active = $n_active;
$resources -> id_parent = $n_id_parent;
$resources -> id_parent['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/categories/' . $n_id_parent;
$resources -> is_root_category = $n_is_root_category;
$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> name -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_name));
$resources -> name -> language[0][0] = $n_name;
$resources -> name -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> name -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;
//
$resources -> name -> language[1][1] = $n_name;
$resources -> name -> language[1][1]['id'] = 2;//$n_l_id;
$resources -> name -> language[1][1]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . 2;//$n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> description -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_desc));
$resources -> description -> language[0][0] = $n_desc;
$resources -> description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;
$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_link_rewrite));
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0] = $n_link_rewrite;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

//
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[1][1] = $n_link_rewrite;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[1][1]['id'] = 2;//$n_l_id;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[1][1]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . 2;//$n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_title));
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_title;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;
//
$resources -> meta_title -> language[1][1] = $n_meta_title;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[1][1]['id'] = $n_l_id_sec;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[1][1]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id_sec;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_description));
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_description;
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;
$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_keywords));
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_keywords;
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;
try {
    $opt = array('resource' => 'categories');
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
    $xml = $webService -> add($opt);
} 
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    czarodziej_log("PS/SYNCHRONIZACJA KATEGORII: " . $e->getMessage(), 1);
    // my log function
    echo "<br>LOG: ".$e->getMessage();
}
}
```

And my code, witch doesn't work, in `c#` is this

```
private string AddCategoryToEShop(string categoryName) 
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Create New Category");
            //PrestaShop.WebService.PrestaShopApi api = PrestashopHelper.CreateNewApiObject();
            string url = _eshopUrl;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url + "/api/categories?schema=blank");
            request.KeepAlive   = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_webServiceUserKey, _webServiceUserPassword);

            request.Method = "POST";

            string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

            string postData = @"<category>

                                        <id_parent xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/categories/0'>2</id_parent>
                                        <active>1</active>
                                        <is_root_category>1</is_root_category>
                                        <name><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>New category name C Sharp</language><language id='2' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/2'>Νέα κατηγορία από C Sharp</language></name>
                                        <link_rewrite><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>-dfs-</language><language id='2' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/2'>-dfs-</language></link_rewrite>
                                        <description><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>New desc ...</language><language id='2'/></description>
                                        <meta_title><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>meta-title</language><language id='2' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/2'>meta-title</language></meta_title>
                                        <meta_description><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>meta desc</language><language id='2'/></meta_description>
                                        <meta_keywords><language id='1' xlink:href='http://localhost/dev/clients/Anthagora/Prestashop/trunk/src/api/languages/1'>some,one,keywords</language><language id='2'/></meta_keywords>
                                    </category>";




            byte[] postDataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            //create recuest content
            request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;// +boundarybytes.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
            // request.GetRequestStream().Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            //request.GetRequestStream().Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string responsText = string.Empty;
            try {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();

                responsText = string.Format("Image of Product {0} added successfully to e-shop", _productId.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                responsText = ex.ToString();
                XtraMessageBox.Show("Exception: (AddCategoryToEShop) " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally {

            }

            uploadProgresslistBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => uploadProgresslistBox.Items.Add(responsText)));

            return responsText;

        }
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: I think you're missing `<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` in the beggining and `</prestashop>` in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a full Java web service API for Prestashop and I think I can help.
At the first sight the postData is wrong. You need to wrap your category node with a Rootelement 'Prestashop'. 
Basically, send a GET request in C#. Then Post Back the same resulat without the node Id. It should work!

I hope it helps.